# Is it possible to rerun GitHub Actions (after commit) if it has failed earlier

Tags: github, github-actions

I am running GitHub Actions when a PR is open. This works fine. Is it possible to run workflows *again* if they failed in their earlier execution due to any error? Currently if I commit a fix, GitHub Actions are not triggered.

```
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  pull_request:
    types: [opened]
    branches: [main]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [16.x]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
          cache: 'npm'
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run build --if-present
      - run: npm test
      - name: serverless deploy
        if: ${{github.event_name=='push'}}
        uses: serverless/github-action@master
        with:
          args: deploy
        env:
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you have event_type `opened`, which triggers when:

> pull request is created

If you want to run your workflow for next commits you need to add event `synchronize`

So you are going yo have:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize]
    branches: [main]
```

or

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]
```

Please check [this](https://frontside.com/blog/2020-05-26-github-actions-pull_request/) for more details.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't trigger any action on the commit

Comment: I think it shoul;d be `types:[opened,synchronize]` and just `branches: [main]`

Comment: In this case it would trigger for any event for PR to main branch. It would be good to start with this first.

Comment: @JatinMehrotra can you consider upvoting my reply if it was helpful for you?

Comment: You marked is answer ;) which I'm grateful for! [How can I upvote answers and comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments)