# Re-run failed GitHub Actions Job after updating code related to that job

Tags: github-actions

I have a workflow that runs about 4 jobs. Job #4 tends to have lots of bugs upon updates. For rapid testing's sake, I would like to be able to update the code related to job #4, then re-run *only* job #4. I know GHA allows you to do this like so:

[image: failed job rerun]

but this only re-runs the job on the same commit (i.e. my new code doesn't get implemented in this re-run of failed job #4).

[Is it possible to rerun github actions (after commit) if it has failed earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69040672/is-it-possible-to-rerun-github-actions-after-commit-if-it-has-failed-earlier) is a similar question but this is for open PRs. I would like to do this on a branch without having a PR just yet.

How can I update code, push it to a branch, then re-run my failed job using the updated code?

Answer (score 2):

As you already mentioned, the re-run feature only allows re-running the *same* commit. There is no way around that in a single repository.

Using the `push` trigger should be just as fast as using re-run. If you need to trigger a specific event, there is not really an option available.

You could take a look at [`nektos/act`](https://github.com/nektos/act), which enables you to run GitHub Actions on your local machine within a docker container. This would be way faster than actually running it in the GitHub repository.